# would like VLC to NOT run always on top but am having no luck

Tags: linux, video, linux-mint, vlc-media-player

I'm running Linux Mint. I'd like VLC to NOT run "always on top", but it only runs that way.

I've tried:

- View : Always On Top (unchecked)
- right click top bar, uncheck Always On Top
- starting vlc with this command: "vlc --no-video-on-top"

So far no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray! I found the answer. This solved all of my problems:

Tools > Preferences > Video > Output change to "OpenGL GLX video output(XCB), save and restart vlc.